# Assign a button to colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Colorbox anchor tag which opens a box with external html.

I want to attach a CSS button to that anchor to operate the Colorbox instead of the text,
but the CSS button already have an anchor class..

How should i go about adding the button to the colorbox anchor?

Button and Colorbox:

```
Button: <a href="#" class="lightbutton">Signup</a>
Colorbox: <p><a class='iframe' href="/comp/form.html">Click Here</a></p>
```

JS:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
                $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
                $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
                $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
                $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
                $(".ajax").colorbox();
                $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
                $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
                $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
                $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                    onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                    onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                    onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                    onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                    onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
                });

                //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
                $("#click").click(function(){ 
                    $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

- I'm not adding the button css because i dont think its relative, if
  it is please state so and ill add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple classes to the same element:

```
<a href="#" class="lightbutton someOtherClass">Signup</a>
```

Styles from both classes will be applied.  If styles conflict, the rules from the strongest selector will be applied.

Comment: hmm i thought i cant, it worked..ill accept it once it lets me, thanks